# Should we have a wiki tag for LaTeX core?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

As we all know extra tags need a lot of work, especially re-tagging of old posts. However there are a number of questions relating to the LaTeX kernel that do not fit in with the existing categories. In most cases LaTeX macros starting with an `\@` would fit into this category. They are not `TeX-core` and do not fit exactly with the `macro` category. What do you think?

Answer (score 16):

I can see the potential usefulness of a [latex-kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-kernel) tag. However, it should only be introduced together with a tag wiki excerpt that clearly states that the tag is *not* meant for general questions about LaTeX. (As a working definition of what [latex-kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-kernel) *is* about, I suggest "anything that requires delving into `source2e`", e.g., my question [What exactly does \@doendpe do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-exactly-does-doendpe-do) would fit.)

EDIT: Some questions may have to be retagged from [latex-project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-project) to [latex-kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-kernel), e.g., [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands)

EDIT 2: I added the [latex-kernel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-kernel) tag to the first three questions and also created a [tag wiki excerpt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/latex-kernel/info).

Answer (score 15):

I'm in favor of such a tag. We just have to be careful that new users don't use it a general LaTeX tag.

Suggestions so far for the tag name where `latex-core` or `latex-kernel`. Actually I find `kernel` now much better because that is the term also used by the original LaTeX2e team, at least it is part of some kernel macro names.